# How to set extra fields for entries using plexus-archiver

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, plexus

I'm working with a maven plugin that is using plexus-archiver in order to create a zip file.
Basically, I'm getting the component inject by Sisu, then I'm traversing a specified fileSet and registering the ones required:

```
zipArchiver.addFile(from_file, to_file);
```

And the zip are being generated properly.

But I need to include an extra-field for the file mime-type in some of those files that are being added to the zip.

how can I do that with plexus-archiver ?

Comment: Why not using the existing plugins like maven-assembly-plugin ?

Comment: Well, because this mojo is part of a plugin that have its own lifecycle and packaging type defined and which goal is not the same as assembly-plugin. This pack mojo is working well, but I need to follow a spec that says some file need include a extra-field for its mime-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the current plexus-archiver (3.0) doesn't support extra-fields.
I have to hack a bit in order to keep using plexus-archive.

The solution was to extend ZipArchiver class and override the method **initZipOutputStream** that provides an object from ZipArchiveOutputStream class.

With it I could create the entry and its extra-field:

```
@Override
protected void initZipOutputStream(ZipArchiveOutputStream pZOut)
        throws ArchiverException, IOException {
    super.initZipOutputStream(pZOut);

ZipArchiveEntry ae = new ZipArchiveEntry(pFile,
            pFile.getName());
ZipExtraField zef = new ContentTypeExtraField(
            Constants.MIME_STRING);
    ae.addExtraField(zef);
    pZOut.putArchiveEntry(ae);
    pZOut.write(content);
    pZOut.closeArchiveEntry();
}
```